# Custom formatting of tokens for date fields

Tags: 8, datetime, tokens

In D8.1, I have created a field called field_date and added it to a content type.

I try to use pathauto to try to configure a URL pattern for the content type like type/year/title. But the token browser does not expose expandable date options for date_field. If I enter it manually, I get "The Path pattern is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_datetime:custom:Y]."

How can I format the output of a token for a date field, the same way I can for a node property like date created?

I've searched the issue queues for contrib token, core datetime and core token system, but I find nothing about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Manage Display** section of your content type can control the output of your date field token.

Under **Custom Display Settings**, make sure the *Token* checkbox is set so you can adjust your token display. Once set, you can navigate to the **Token** tab where you can set your date field's **Format** to *Custom* and add your custom PHP [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) string in the **Date/time format** field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful if you want to show the data always in the same format when using tokens. Do you also know how to use different formats? So is it possible to have multiple view-modes for tokens?

Comment: You're better off asking this as a separate question.

Comment: What a strange use of view modes!

Answer (score 5):

The Token module added direct support for datetime and daterange fields in December 2016. See https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/2786181.

You should be able to use something like `[node:field_datetime:date:custom:Y]`

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use:

[node:field_[YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE]_date:0:date:custom:Y]